# Max-Flow: Detect if a given edge is found in some Min-Cut

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Given a network $G=(V,E)$ , a max flow f and an edge $e \in E$ , I need to find an efficient algorithm in order to detect whether there is some min cut which contains $e$.
Another question is, how do I decide whether if $e$ is the lightest edge of at least one minimal cut?

I've thought about running Ford-Fulkerson algorithm, and then increasing / decreasing the capacity of the given edge and see what happens, but I haven't came up with something that might help me solve the problem.

I'd be grateful if anyone could point me to the solution, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution for the first question: Suppose $w(e)$ is the weight of $e$, calculate min-cut value for $G$, suppose is $C$. Then we remove $e$ from $G$ to make $G'$; again we calculate the min-cut value for $G'$, suppose is $C'$, if $C-C'\ge w(e)$, then this concludes that $e$, participating in at least one min-cut (that you already know it), otherwise $e$ does not belong to any min-cut.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984852/max-flow-detect-if-a-given-edge-is-found-in-some-min-cut/16987517#16987517) to SO answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have rational capacities, multiply¹ them to become integral and then decrease the capacity of $e$ by e.g. $0.5$¹. Then every two cuts differ only by integers (before you decrease) and a cut that contains $e$ can't get minimal if it wasn't before. On the other hand a minimal cut that contains $e$ has now strictly smaller capacity than before and thus it has a smaller capacity than all cuts that do not contain $e$ (they weren't decreased).

Now you compute a maximal flow and if its value decreased, any minimal cut (like the one that separates vertices reachable from the source in the residual network from the rest) contains $e$, if it didn't decrease, $e$ is not contained in any minimal cut.

¹ <sub>If you don't like the multiplication, you can also compute the smallest common denominator $d$ of all weights and use $\frac{d}{2}$ instead of $0.5$.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there are still some issues that are not clear enough :
1 - I aim to find out whether e is contained in some minimal cut , not in every minimal cut
2 - I don't want to find the lightest edge , I'd like to find out if e is the lightest edge in some minimal cut

Comment: i don't know if e is in some minimal cut , I want to find out whether it's found in a minimal cut or not

Comment: @Itamar: I edited your question and my answer, according to the comments on [SO], so please remove (and reformulate) your comments here to.